Position scrollbar top of scroll bar when loading application
I am getting an issue where when my sidebar loads in the Panel, the scroll bar is all the way to the bottom of the buttons. I need it to position at the top of the sidebar buttons. I've tried a few things and none seem to work. I have a feeling that somewhere in my code it is recognizing the last button as the first or something similiar. That or I have conflicting container properties that is disregarding the code I've put in.
    ' Declare VScrollBar1 with WithEvents
Private WithEvents VScrollBar1 As New VScrollBar()

Private Sub MainScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Call a method to initialize dynamic controls
    InitializeDynamicControls()
    Panel1.Visible = True

    ' Add the VScrollBar control to the form
    Controls.Add(VScrollBar1)
    ' Set the properties of the VScrollBar control
    VScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right
    VScrollBar1.Minimum = 0
    VScrollBar1.Maximum = Panel2.Height
    VScrollBar1.LargeChange = Panel2.Height - Panel1.Height ' Set the large change value
    VScrollBar1.SmallChange = 20 ' Set the small change value

    ' Set the value of the VScrollBar to 0 to ensure it starts at the top
    VScrollBar1.Value = 0

    ' Set the vertical scroll position of Panel2 to 0
    Panel2.VerticalScroll.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeDynamicControls()
    ' Define an array with button names in descending order
    Dim buttonNames() As String = {"Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 5", "Button 4", "Button 3", "Button 2", "Document understanding"}

    ' Add buttons dynamically based on the buttonNames array
    For Each buttonName As String In buttonNames
        Dim button As New System.Windows.Forms.Button() ' Fully qualify Button class
        button.Text = buttonName
        button.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf OpenForm ' Add click event handler
        Panel2.Controls.Add(button)
    Next
End Sub

' Inside the MainScreen class
Private WithEvents docunderstanding As New DocUnderstanding()

Private Sub OpenForm(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Handle button click event
    Dim button As System.Windows.Forms.Button = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button)

    ' Check which button was clicked
    Select Case button.Text
        Case "Document understanding"
            ' Show docunderstanding UserControl
            docunderstanding.Show()

            ' Hide Panel1
            Panel1.Visible = False

            ' Bring docunderstanding UserControl to the front
            docunderstanding.BringToFront()
        Case Else
            ' Handle other buttons here
            MessageBox.Show("This module is not yet developed, please email matthew@zoljan.com for urgent need!")
    End Select
End Sub

' Event handler for the Scroll event of the VScrollBar
Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
    ' Adjust the location of Panel2 based on the scrollbar value
    Panel2.Location = New Point(Panel2.Location.X, -VScrollBar1.Value)
End Sub

Could it be the order I have positioned the buttons? Any help is much appreciated.

I have resolved it.
I changed the Dockstyle.Top to Dockstyle.Bottom:
    Private Sub InitializeDynamicControls()
    ' Define an array with button names in descending order
    Dim buttonNames() As String = {"Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 6", "Button 5", "Button 4", "Button 3", "Button 2", "Document understanding"}

    ' Add buttons dynamically based on the buttonNames array
    For Each buttonName As String In buttonNames
        Dim button As New System.Windows.Forms.Button() ' Fully qualify Button class
        button.Text = buttonName
        button.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf OpenForm ' Add click event handler
        Panel2.Controls.Add(button)
    Next
End Sub

